# Python: "import ... as" causes incorrect reference

Tags: python, import, module

I've noticed a peculiar behavior in how python handles module names.

If I write:

```
import a.b
import a
```

and then attempt to reference something in module a.b, it works without a problem.

However, if I attempt something only slightly different:

```
import a.b
import c as a
```

and then attempt to reference something in module a.b, I get an error, saying:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'b'

I understand that the obvious solution is simply to not have two different modules I refer to by the same name. However, I'm still curious what caused this change in behaviour. Why does one work and not the other?

Comment: isnt correct way to import stuff would be "from module import module/class/whatever" ? EDIT: nm wrong formating caused me to write this comment.

Comment: Use Ctrl-K or the editor's code sample button when you include code in a post, and all the linebreaks and spacing will show up correctly, plus you get syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 11):

Why do you expect it to work? All 4 of your import statements are assignments to the variable `a`. Thus if you assign `c` to `a`, it overwrites the contents with something that doesn't have a `.b` attribute.

---

Here's what happens in the first case:

1. When `import a.b` is run, Python loads module `a`, and then loads the module `a.b` into the loaded `a` module's attribute `b`. It then assigns the result to the variable `a`.
2. The `import a` doesn't import anything new, because module `a` is already loaded. It simply reassigns the same module from `sys.modules['a']` to `a`.

Here's what happens in the second case:

1. When `import a.b` is run, Python loads module `a`, and then loads the module `a.b` into the loaded `a` module's attribute `b`. It then assigns the result to the variable `a`.
2. When `import c as a` is run, it loads the module `c`, and then assigns that module to variable `a`, *overwriting* the contents (`a = sys.modules['c']`). You could verify this by comparing the contents of `sys.modules['a']` with the contents of `a` - they'll be different in this case.

Comment: This makes a lot of since. I've been using java recently, so I considered "a" and "a.b" to be separate from each other. It's didn't occur to me that modules were being stored as objects and that I was overwriting them.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

if you `import c as a`

it will overwrite your previous `a`

so if you try to call `a.b` you really call `c.b`

Answer (score 3):

In the first case, `a` refers to the actual package `a` (which contains the module `b`). This means that `a.b` refers to something which is contained by `a`.

In the second case, `a` refers to module `c.py`. It's as though you tried `import c; a = c`. Now, if `c` doesn't have an attribute `b`, it will fail.

Answer (score 2):

When you do an "import as" statement, you are really doing an assignment.  So if you do this

```
import matplotlib as mp
```

you are assigning the namespace for `matplotlib` to `mp`.

That carries all of the usual implications of assignment.